# Installing bundle from maven on Karaf Restart failing on Karaf 3.0.5

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I want to install a bundle (if it is not already installed) from maven on Karaf restart. So to achieve this I added it in the `/etc/startup.properties` as below:-

```
# add here bundles you want to install while system startup, e.g. 
# joda-time/joda-time/2.9/joda-time-2.9.jar=10
mvn\:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.7.4 = 10
```

But on trying to start karaf I am getting the below exception:-

```
jabongs-MacBook-Pro-4:apache-servicemix-6.1-2.0 debraj$ bin/servicemix
Please wait while Apache ServiceMix is starting...
Error installing bundle listed in startup.properties with url: mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.7.4 and startlevel: 10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.destroy(Main.java:533)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:173)
```

The same bundle installs fine when I try to install it via the below command after Karaf has started:-

```
karaf@root>bundle:install mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.7.4
Bundle ID: 237
```

Can some one help me in the following:-

1. Why is the bundle installation failing on Karaf start?
2. I am seeing the error only when Karaf is started for the first time. After that I am not seeing the above error nor the bundle is installed. So is it that Karaf tries to install the bundle in `startup.properties` only when it is started for the very first time?
3. If the answer to `#2` is yes is there some other place in Karaf where I can place the bundle name, so that Karaf tries to install it every time (if it is not already installed) on restart?

Environment:-

- `Karaf 3.0.5`
- `Apache Serviemix 6.1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mvn: url resolver is probably not wired up. Try adding it without the mvn: and ensure the jar is in the system/ folder.

If this is for business-code and not container/product extension type code your best bet is to build a feature and add it to the etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg featuresBoot

Comment: I have done what you have suggested. Created a `features.xml` and added it to the `/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg` 's `featureBoot` and working fine.